# PyCharm: Search keymaps by key combination?

Tags: python, windows, pycharm, hotkeys, keymapping

I'm messing with keymaps in PyCharm. Is there a way to search for keymaps by key combination?

I'm specifically trying to change the keymaps for

- run selection (alt+shift+e by default in Windows)
- replace all (alt+a by default in Windows)

Comment: Are you perhaps pertaining to this? https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/configuring-keyboard-and-mouse-shortcuts.html

Comment: Yep! If you post this as an answer, I will vote for it. Clicking on the magnifying glass next to the search box does it.

Comment: Do you know whether there is a sneaky way to change the replace all hotkey? It doesn't seem to be configurable in the keymap interface.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you perhaps looking for [this?](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/configuring-keyboard-and-mouse-shortcuts.html)